# Problems with bucardo installation

Tags: postgresql, replication, bucardo

I have postgresql 9.5 and postgresql-plperl-9.5 and bucardo version 5.4.1

after bucardo install

```
Current connection settings:
1. Host:           localhost
2. Port:           5432
3. User:           postgres
4. Database:       postgres
5. PID directory:  /var/run/bucardo
```

I'm trying to start bucardo

but error is "
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  relation "bucardo.bucardo_config" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT setting FROM bucardo.bucardo_config WHERE LOWER(name)...
                            ^ at /usr/bin/bucardo line 545.
"
Where is a problem here?

Answer (score 1):

If you set a custom connection configurations for the postgresql, you'll need to specify it after each 'bucardo' command.
Only then, 'bucardo' will look for its tables in the right place.
For example:

```
bucardo -U bucardo -d bucardo -p 5000 -P my_password install
```

Also, make sure that you executed the following beforehand:

```
CREATE USER bucardo SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'my_password';
CREATE DATABASE bucardo;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE bucardo TO bucardo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create bucardo user and database. 
Follow

https://www.installvirtual.com/how-to-install-bucardo-for-postgres-replication/

Answer (score 0):

Please create table using below query in postgresql bucardo database

```
CREATE TABLE bucardo.bucardo_config (
  name     TEXT        NOT NULL, -- short unique name, maps to %config inside Bucardo
  setting  TEXT        NOT NULL,
  about    TEXT            NULL, -- long description
  type     TEXT            NULL, -- sync or goat
  item     TEXT            NULL, -- which specific sync or goat
  cdate    TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
COMMENT ON TABLE bucardo.bucardo_config IS $$Contains configuration variables for a specific Bucardo instance$$;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bucardo_config_unique ON bucardo.bucardo_config(LOWER(name)) WHERE item IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bucardo_config_unique_name ON bucardo.bucardo_config(name,item,type) WHERE item IS NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE bucardo.bucardo_config ADD CONSTRAINT valid_config_type CHECK (type IN ('sync','goat'));

ALTER TABLE bucardo.bucardo_config ADD CONSTRAINT valid_config_isolation_level
CHECK (name <> 'isolation_level' OR (setting IN ('serializable','repeatable read')));
```

Comment: I don't find that this is a good advise, as the table schema can change between bucardo versions, and the questions is a installation/usage trouble, that don't really need this kind of workaround.